# first three months from signed date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have columns `id, signed_date, begin_date`  and have this query:

```
select id, signed_date, count(*)
FROM table t1
WHERE   is_ever = 'true'
AND   signed_date >= '2021-01-01'
group by id, signed_date
```

I need from `signed_date` to or had within the first three months delay.

---

If had then in DB are `begin_date` since when start delay. can't use CTE

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function should help:

```
select id, signed_date, count(*)
FROM table t1
WHERE   is_ever = 'true'
AND   signed_date = '2021-01-01' and begin_date between signed_date AND signed_date + interval '3 months'
group by id, signed_date
```

Comment: What is this  `WHERE '2021-01-01`? because I need id who signed from 2021-01-01

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and the expected result to your question? Looks like you rrequirements are not 100% clear

Comment: Every ID have signed date 2021-01-01 or 2021-05-20 or 2022-03-15 and more... So i need only ID who signed from 2021-01-01 and then from signed date check delay in first three month

Comment: Where i get the `delay` from?

Comment: delay from signed date for each id

Comment: deley beween what? Do you mean time between singed and begin?

Comment: `is_ever = 'true'` between  `ID` signed date and signed date + 3 months

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247647/discussion-between-nickname-used-and-jens).